# HTML/CSS background-image will apply to element but not a class selector?

Tags: html, css

For the life of me i cannot get this to work, any help will be much appreciated!

I am trying to apply a background image to a div class, for some reason the image will not show up, yet when i apply the same image to the body, it works perfectly, i have created a new html/css file to test and play around with it, see the examples below.

This works

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="topNav">
    <p>Content here</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url("images/topNav-bg.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

This doesnt

```
<body>
  <div class="topNav">
    <p>Content here</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.topNav {
  background-image: url("images/topNav-bg.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

The only difference in the one that doesnt work to the one that does, is the css selector points to the class and not the element, any idea why it could be that I am having this problem? I have tried adding an ID also to the div, thinking with more specifity it might work, I have also tried making the div class width and height 100% thinking if the size is set it would work, but it still does nothing, and also, it surely wouldnt work on the body element if that were the case?
My css file is linked and path to the image is all correct also, otherwise it surely wouldnt work when I apply the css rule to the body element?
This seems really basic but has been bugging me for ages now!

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

EDIT

the actual code in my working page is as follows:
HTML

```
    <div class="topNav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Create account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contributions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Talk</a></li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Not logged in</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.topNav {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 176px;
    background-image: url('../images/topNav-bg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90.83%;
}
```

I thought it may be something else interfering, thats why i made the example to try and isolate the problem, it repeated itself though after I had removed all other styling from the div.

Comment: What other styles are applied to `.topNav`? Could you share an actual example of what you are facing?

Comment: You dont have the div closed or body

Comment: Are you write the conection with the css file fine?

Comment: ah yes that was a typo here, in the actual file it is closed. the link to the css file is also ok as stated in my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body div .topNav {
  background-image: url("images/topNav-bg.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I think this might work

Comment: Hmm, this (answer above) doesn't but body, topNav does strangely, doesnt work with the space only with the comma any idea why? is it to do with specificity? Thanks for the tip, hadnt thought of trying that!

Comment: try body  div  .topNav {  }

Comment: Yes space act as a seperator while defining css for multiple class or tags

Comment: @JamieBullock `body, .topNav` means `body` and `.topNav`. That means the style get's applied to `body` again.

Comment: That will not work, he is using div, he have to establish the height and width. Also, that property that attempts to use does not work with div

Comment: hmm so a background image can not be applied to a div, unless the height is explicitly set (with px not percent) yet it will work on the body? Will it work with the HTML5 elements, "nav" "aside" etc? although i am hesitant to use them much due to old browser support issues. Thanks for your help guys, I am trying to teach myself html,css,javascript, so the explanation as to why or why not it wouldnt work is much more helpful than just the answer. I am currently trying to recreate the wikipedia homepage as practise, although it looks like a simple page it is quite complex to get it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

You are using div, you have to set the height and width.

```
  <style type="text/css">
.topNav{
    background-image: url("http://mejorconsalud.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/manzanas.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Ah, I forget, the property repeat-x dont work with div...

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some inherited styles or such that apply to the `ul` that you are not showing us (a `float` for example), that collapses the content.

Try applying the following style:

```
.topNav:after {
  content:'';
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
```

Sometimes when styles start stacking up inheritance becomes a problem you need to deal with. One such scenario is when you use `float`s. Then the `floated` element might get collapsed and wont have height unless you give it one or apply something like the style I suggest here.